# Migrating an Access Database into SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

To my surprise and delight I read that an adminsitrator can import (nearly directly) an Access 2007 database into a sharepoint site. Automagically, the database in transformed into lists and views with some table lookup thrown in for good measure. With Access 2007 installed on the client machine, even the forms and what not can still be reused.

To me... this sounds to good to be true.

Has anyone actually dones this? With all this good news, where is the bad stuff and pitfalls to this. Depending on the size of the database, wouldn't this some how "gum up the works" in the SharPoint database?

Sources:
http://madhurahuja.blogspot.com/2007/01/adding-data-to-sharepoint-l-ists-in.html
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/17745835-a861-4984-9f44-7291fdae7d07

Comment: You are moving the database to SharePoint but still using Access locally for forms and reports?

I have to ask why, what advantage are you getting here?

Comment: I would like to migrate from the current "proprietary" solution easliy without messsing to much with user expectations. They have been using the access gernerated UI and don't seem too displeased by it. The other option is the practically rewrite the application that they are using. My development time is limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint has no referential integrity. This is the main reason I can't see it as being usable for any kind of database operations, since without RI, you've just got a collection of lists, and not a database. This doesn't mean Sharepoint is not good for some things, but replacing an Access/Jet database entirely seems to me one of the obvious things it is *not* viable for.

Comment: If a field in View A is required to come from View B, isn't that RI? Sharepoint has this capability with Lists. Very limited, but it works.

Comment: Where is that done? At the UI level? If so, that isn't RI at all -- RI has to be at the database engine level or it isn't RI. The point is that Sharepoint has no way of enforcing RI because it's a flat data structure -- there are no multiple tables/lists, just a presentation that makes is seem like there are.